# When does a c# pre-build event happen?

Tags: c#, pre-build-event

The question of getting the compilation date/time of a program sometimes crops up here. I had an idea for how to do this. So I write a tiny console application which produces a CompileInfo.cs file containing the current date/time...

public class CompileInfo {public readonly static string compileStamp = "2012-09-27 17:58:42";}

I added that file to my main project and added an invocation of the tiny console app to the pre-build events for the project. Then, in the project I can access CompileInfo.compileStamp to get the compilation date/time.

The console app is invoked on every build, BUT the CompileInfo.cs file that gets assembled is the old one - the one that existed before the console app ran. If I build the project again I always get  the CompileInfo.cs file created on the previous build.

I assume that my understanding of pre-build events is defective. I would be grateful to be enlightened.

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop.

Comment: Thy occur before the build, but are asynchronous

Comment: Clive, you might want to reword your question to ask how to run something that generates files that are used in the build. (I don't know how, I'm interested in the solution myself)

Comment: MSBuild would be one way to do it but another would be to have a batch file that called yours then compiled using the command line. Wouldn't be integrated of course but if this was important for release builds, might not be a big deal.

Comment: And another way to get what you want though in a slightly different way would be a custom assembly attribute. For instance see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/11/custom-assemblyinfo-attributes.html

Comment: @TonyHopkinson How exactly would a custom assembly attribute solve the problem that the build doesn't wait for the pre-build to finish?

Comment: @CrazyCasta Laterally. It wouldn't use pre-build at all, so something similar to the way Assembly build version gets done but with a date and time.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I think you're going to need to spell it out. My picture is that the build version is something unique, that you can't specify your own code that gets run before something is built. I would be glad to be proved wrong however.

Comment: Not exacltly sure of the exact how myself. I'll have a play over the weekend. I think it can be done, mind you've there have been occasions where I've thought wrong. :(

Comment: Thanks to all who responded. I look forward to (maybe) learning how to kick off something that is guaranteed to finish before the build starts.

Comment: @CliveTooth Change your question to ask for a way to run something that will finish before the build starts. If you put it in the question you are more likely to get a response.